# trying to build up an OrderedDict object in Python to eventually convert into JSON via simplejson

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

The inputs are going to be something like:

```
List1 - a python list of any size of conditions to be ANDed
List2 - a python list of any size of conditions to be ORed
```

Eventually, I want to produce JSON output that looks like this:

> {"view": {"ANDS" : [ { "status": "status_field", "operator":
>   "operator_field", "value": "value_field}, ... ], "ORS" : [ { "status":
>   "status_field", "operator": "operator_field", "value": "value_field},
>   ... ]}}

My plan is to leverage the [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson) library to eventually write something like:

```
import simplejson as json
json.dumps(OrderedDictObject)
```

which I understand should handle the conversion.

My question, not having a lot of experience using OrderedDict objects, is how to go about writing a function to build up such an object, having parsed through `List1` and `List2` in order to generate the object to pass to `json.dumps()`

Any best practices here?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Since JSON data types map almost directly onto Python data types, just create a Python dictionary that looks the way you want and pass it to `json.dumps()` and you should be all set.  If you tried that and it didn't do what you want or expected, let us know where the problems are.

Comment: Apologies, mostly I'm not sure how to go about setting up the dictionary object to pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your two Python lists:

> List1 - a python list of any size of conditions to be ANDed
>   List2 - a python list of any size of conditions to be ORed

Then you could do something like this:

```
mydict = { 'views': { 'ANDS': List1, 'ORS': List2 } }
```

Which you'll note exactly mirrors the structure of your the JSON example you've posted.  Given:

```
List1 = [ { "status": "status_field", "operator": "operator_field", "value": "value_field"} ]
List2 = [ { "status": "status_field", "operator": "operator_field", "value": "value_field"} ]
```

This would get you JSON output like this:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(mydict, indent=True)
{
 "views": {
  "ORS": [
   {
    "status": "status_field", 
    "operator": "operator_field", 
    "value": "value_field"
   }
  ], 
  "ANDS": [
   {
    "status": "status_field", 
    "operator": "operator_field", 
    "value": "value_field"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: apologies, I should have explained this a bit better... `List1` and `List2` are going to be formed like `[["status_field", "operator_field", "value_field"],...]` to make later construction easier.

Comment: ...but you want to convert them into dictionaries, as in your JSON example?